# MySQL Prepared Statememt for Multiple Insert

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql

I am using NodeJS and mysql2 package, and I'm trying to do a very simple insert query for a dynamic number of rows at once.

The [mysql2 package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) has 2 options for running a query, execute() and query(). I would assume that I only have to prepare the following statement for example:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, score) VALUES ?
```

So I used execute() API with the query above, and a values object:

```
await poolConnection.execute(query, [[["id1", 1], ["id2", 2]]]);
```

As described in their documentation, this should be escaped and turn into a valid query like so:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, score) VALUES ('id1', 1), ('id2', 2)
```

But it fails with the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Which means that bottom line - the following PREPARE statement does not work. But why can we not prepare a statement that inserts multiple rows, while preparing an single insert works?

```
SET @s = 'INSERT INTO my_table (user_id, score) VALUES ?; PREPARE myStatement FROM @s;
```

I will say that this works as expected when using the query() API of the package, but this does not prepare the statement for reuse, which is pretty bad in very high scale of queries.

What am I doing wrong and should I just use query() instead?

Comment: I think you have an extra level of nesting, it should just be `[["id1", 1], ["id2", 2]]`.

Comment: Please look at this url's example for clarification of the INSERT syntax.  - https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert.asp

Comment: It is not about the parameters, it is about the prepared statement that does not work. The link to INSERT examples have nothing to do with the questions.

Comment: Paramaterization isn't just concatenating stuff into your query. It uses placeholders, but the statement itself needs to be syntactically correct. You would need `INSERT INTO my_table (columnsHere) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)` so you need to know how many rows you are inserting in order to construct the statement correctly.

Comment: `VALUES ?` is incorrect, it must be `VALUES (?, ?)` (with the same amount of `?` as there are columns in the column list).